are the usual quantified statements independent of domains of discourse?
let U be the property of being an unicorn
and take the following proposition
P = it's not the case that there is a x such that U(x).`
P is a quantified proposition, and my question is: What is the domain of quantification of P?
the problem here is the following: if we say that the domain is a class of "possible things" we will need a definition of this class, and then we will come to a circular situation if we try to define this class of things because we will use quantified statements over this domain we want to define, which is the class of possible things.
We have two solutions:

denying that classes are the object that we quantify over when we make existential statements

denying the need for a domain when we use a quantified proposition


It seems to me that (1) is more promising, what do you think?
*Update:
Firstly, I mean by (1) the case where we accept that the meaning of P doesn't depend on the definition of a class which is the domain of discourse. Thus, we should think of another semantic for the quantified propositions, like the monist semantic that holds that the World is the domain on which we quantify over not the classes. The World could be defined as complex that is the truthmaker of negative existentials.
Yes, we can use this trick to define a "class of actual or possible things", but as a nominalist, I think I'm better with a physical or objective "World" than an abstract object like classes.
Secondly, saying that we don't need the definition of a "specific" domain of discourse won't do. because we will assume in this situation that our statement is true in (every interpretation or domain of discourse) here again we use a quantified proposition over the class of (interpretations) and (domains) which is also in need of a definition, a definition we cannot provide without the use of quantified statements or relying on the (World).

In FOL, the domain of the quantifiers isn't specified by the sentences, as you point out. Instead, the domain is part of the semantics: it's specified by a first-order structure. The same set of sentences can be modelled by many different first-order structures, hence can be interpreted with many different domains. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_(mathematical_logic)#Definition

yes, but does that respond to the question?

Yes, it does. You can reason within a system of FOL using the rules of inference, without having specified a first-order structure or even a domain. This is common in mathematics, for example, where you successfully reason about mathematical objects without ever specifying a model for the set-theoretic axioms. Instead, it's understood that the inferences you make would hold in any model. In such circumstances you "use" quantified propositions without needing to specify a domain. Your option #2 is vague in some ways (e.g. what is "use"?) but what I am describing seems to fit with #2.

Very good,
Last question; and bear with me. Don't you think that what are you saying means that our understanding of the meaning of quantifiers  is independent of our understanding of domains? that we can understand the meaning of "every" without liking it with the idea of a domain?

No, I don't think that. Any talk about "our understanding" of quantifiers or domains will be clearer if you distinguish between 1) the understanding that a person has when reasoning within a given system of predicate logic solely by using the rules of inference, without thinking of the semantics, or 2) the understanding that a person has when reasoning within that system but thinking of an intended semantics, or 3) the metatheoretic understanding that a person has about various semantics for that system. In each case I think your questions have answers, but they differ between the 3 cases.

Your distinction is well noted. I am concerned with 2, when I hold a proposition such as P, I'm thinking of some semantics, about the meaning of quantifiers in everyday discourse, I agree, I don't have to link quantifiers with "classes" and "domain" when I am just playing with symbols using the rules of inference, but when I'm not just playing, when I make meaningful statements (like P) I need to know if the meaning of quantifier terms depends on the idea of a domain of discourse.

See Nonexistent Objects for discussion and theories about the issue of "fictional" objects.

"we can understand the meaning of "every" without liking it with the idea of a domain?" Yes; "all" means all. Our intuition about it is quite fundamental: we need a rigorous semantics of quantifiers in order to manage "special" contexts, like mathematical theories.

See also Quantifiers and Quantification and Generalized Quantifiers and Plural Quantification and Ontological Commitment.

I do not follow why we need a set of possible things rather than of actual things to interpret P = ¬ ∃x U(x), or why we need quantification to define that set (in simplest cases, we can just list its elements). Even assuming that we do need quantification for that, it will be quantification in meta-language, not the original object language, and there will be no circularity. And yes, interpretation of quantifiers does explicitly depend on the chosen domain of discourse, as do truth values of propositions with them.

See debate: Terence Parsons, Are There Nonexistent Objects? (1982) and Jaakko Hintikka, Are There Nonexistent Objects? Why Not? But Where are They? (Synthese, 1984)

To Condifold:
I agree with you concerning the first point, I talked about "possible things" to take into account the ideas of those who believe in non-existent objects (I agree with you)
Concerning the matter of defining the class of "actual things", I don't agree, because when you are listing its element you will come to a point where you believe that your list L is exhaustive, a point when you hold a negative existential statement in the form
Q = ¬ ∃x o(x) and I(x)
where O is the property of being an object and I the property of not being listed in L.
the circularity is clear I hope

Also, I don't think we can get over the problem if we think in terms of metalanguages. The problem persists even in the metalanguage, so considering another metalanguage to solve the problem won't do, for we will have an infinite semantic regression when we try to understand the meaning of quantified propositions in each of these languages.

The following answer comes out of Brouwer's tradition (SEP).

P = it's not the case that there is a x such that U(x).

You are asking after the domain of discourse, including what is it and what is the rationale to justify a given answer. In type theory, it is common to talk about the set U, which is the universal set relative to a statement. But before we go down this path, it is right to say that when constructing a formal semantics to address questions about domains of discourse, in some ways, one is free to construct any system one chooses, usually as long as it has key properties like avoids paradox or combinatorial explosion.
In other words, there is no one right or irrefutable approach to dealing with constructing domains of discourse, but rather pluralism prevails. Thus naive set theory and ZFC which both formalize set theoretical systems approach domain in slightly different ways. Type theories might also. I'm going to pick one particular type system to continue to frame the response regarding the construction you call P.
Intuitionistic type theory (SEP) is a particular type of type theory (and there are flavors of it to boot). In ITT, we deal with things like proof objects, categories, sets, and judgements. Note, that as long as the semantics of P are given for the compositional elements of P (quantification, binding, predicates, etc.) we have leeway in deciding what within which framework P operates. This is important because a proposition is part of a formal system, and the rules of the formal system are the axiomatic theory expressed in meta- and object language. And all languages are games, at least according to Wittgenstein.
One way to specify a domain of discourse is to provide an intensional definition of an extension. For instance, in dealing with the naturals, PA specifies the very definition of the naturals. This of course, was important because the rigorization of a formal system with arithmetic cannot be finite, and thus cannot be expressed by extension. Intuitively, the proof that naturals have no upper bound is as simple as the notion that primes have no upper bound.
You may object that we have any ability to construct a formal system, because a formal system is a real definition. But at this point, the idea that we cannot engineer a system, especially given the fall of geometry from a realist interpretation of Euclidean geometry into a plethora of non-Euclidean geometries reveals the same fact that reverse mathematics teaches us about formal systems: system are constructed out of logics to further our goals, and in no sense physical artifacts waiting to be discovered. At least according to Brouwer and his intellectual descendants according to the doctrine of mathematical intuitionism (SEP).
Thus, the domain on P at first glance might easily be x | x is an animal or alternatively x | x is any real thing. Or it could be anything else that serves your need x | x is a creature in Narnia or Middle Earth. Notice that reality and fiction are two approaches to providing a characterization of a context in a language, a formal notion usually represented by Γ. Both the context and the domain of your binding is determined by your ambitions, and this is consistent with the fact that human beings are demonstrably agents that operate according to instrumental rationality (SEP).
Lastly, you seem troubled by the fact that you would need an infinite regress to make sense of domains of discourse, and yet, practically speaking, the limits to the construction of a domain are provided by the process of construction. But infinite regress is a strength, not a weakness. Mathematical induction and coinduction, for instance are extremely powerful thinking tools. And to boot infinite regress sits comfortably with an interpretation of infinity that is potential rather than actual. In ITT, practical judgment is the mechanism which regulates our intentional rationality.
With ITT, we are now free to construct our categories and sets in any way that serve our needs, including evolving a universe of small types (SEP). From the article:

Martin-Löf’s first version of type theory (Martin-Löf 1971a) had an axiom stating that there is a type of all types. This was proved inconsistent by Girard who found that the Burali-Forti paradox could be encoded in this theory... To overcome this pathological impredicativity, but still retain some of its expressivity, Martin-Löf introduced in 1972 a universe of small types closed under all type formers of the theory, except that it does not contain itself... In Martin-Löf (1975) the universe is extended to a countable hierarchy of universes.

So, within ITT, we now have a framework for applying any arbitrary intension, extension, or even ostension to constructing a domain of discourse for a variable that we leverage to serve our needs and our inferences. Not only is this expressive, but it aligns well with how natural language ontologies (SEP) themselves may be constructed in practice. Certainly, such a formal semantics is far superior to describing the speculative metaphysics of the Scholastics, than anything ZFC can handle.
